# presolve in Rglpk and R implementations of CLP

Tags: r, linear-programming

I needed to solve some binary linear programming problems whose constraint matrices were very large (to the point that they could not even be generated); so I thought: why not make sparse constraint matrices? However none of the LP solvers I knew (`lpSolve`, `Rsymphony`) seemed to be able to handle sparse constraint matrices.
So I found and installed `Rglpk`, which handles sparse matrices via `slam`.
Then I was able to make my matrices using `xtabs` with the *sparse* option, convert them to the `slam` format and submit them to the solver. I was impressed with the improvement in performance when using `Rglpk` as opposed to `lpSolve` (which was also slower than `Rsymphony` on some other problems). And in `Rglpk` I could also use a *presolve* option, which `lpSolve`  also had but actually ignored.

However, now I have two doubts.

1. when I solved a large problem with `Rglpk`, I first tried with `presolve=TRUE`, and it finished in less than 20 min.
   But when I tried the same with `presolve=FALSE`, not only it had not yet finished after a few hours, but by setting `verbose=TRUE` I could see that the objective function was getting to even better values compared the 'optimal' value found by the `presolve=TRUE` run.
   **Q1: shouldn't `presolve=TRUE` just accelerate the process, without actually changing the problem in such a way that a less optimal solution is obtained?**
2. while looking for more information on `Rglpk`,  I found [this report](https://prod-ng.sandia.gov/techlib-noauth/access-control.cgi/2013/138847.pdf) where several LP solvers were compared.
   The report seems to conclude that CLP is the best open-source solver. I looked for `R` implementations, but I could only find `clpAPI` [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clpAPI/index.html), which does not seem to have a high-level command like `Rglpk`, `Rsymphony` and `lpSolve` do. It looks like it can handle sparse matrices: command `loadMatrixCLP` seems to take row and column indices + values for the non-zero elements; but clearly that would require some work. And then I would still not know how to handle the various low-level solvers, options, etc. And I can't find any reference to presolve techniques.
   **Q2: does anybody know of a high-level implementation of `CLP` in R?**
   [`Rsymphony`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rsymphony/index.html) should be pretty good (COIN-OR etc), and there is a cursory mention of sparse matrices in its reference manual, but then I can find no clear explanation of how sparse matrices can be passed to the solver.
   I consulted [this webpage](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html), but could not find anything clearly hitting the target.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT : example of problem solved with `Rsymphony`, `lpSolve` and `Rglpk`**

After further searches following up from sascha's advice, it emerged that `Rsymphony` could handle sparse matrices.
So I tried that, and found that it worked; however, `lpSolve` found an additional solution which `Rsymphony` did not.

In the example below, the initial data.frame `t0` represents 7 objects (identified by property 'ID'), each of which is associated with a property 'SC' (unique for each object), and an array property 'FP'.
As I don't know how to handle array properties well in `R`, I unmerged the initial data separately for the 'SC' and 'FP' properties, and tagged the corresponding rows using property 'prop_to_handle'.

The goal of the optimisation is to select 1 object with SC=="A", 2 objects with SC=="B" and 1 object with SC=="C", such that the number of unique FP's in the solution is maximised.
I discussed this topic (counting unique features) elsewhere in StackExchange posts; so far nobody has come up with alternative solutions to the one I am implementing here, which consists in adding 1 binary variable for each FP feature, and then appropriate constraints ensuring the absence of contradictions.
In this case there are 7 ID's and 12 distinct FP features, therefore 19 binary variables need to be assigned.

```
#Initial data
t0 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7), prop_to_handle = c("FP", 
"FP", "FP", "SC", "FP", "FP", "FP", "SC", "FP", "FP", "FP", "SC", 
"FP", "FP", "FP", "SC", "FP", "FP", "FP", "SC", "FP", "FP", "FP", 
"SC", "FP", "FP", "FP", "SC"), SC = c(NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, 
NA, "A", NA, NA, NA, "B", NA, NA, NA, "B", NA, NA, NA, "B", NA, 
NA, NA, "C", NA, NA, NA, "C"), N = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
1, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
NA, NA, NA, 1), FP = c(100, 200, 300, NA, 100, 400, 600, NA, 
500, 200, 300, NA, 500, 400, 600, NA, 500, 900, 700, NA, 250, 
150, 300, NA, 250, 175, 350, NA)), .Names = c("ID", "prop_to_handle", 
"SC", "N", "FP"), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")

#Installing and loading packages
if (length(find.package(package="Rsymphony",quiet=TRUE))==0) install.packages("Rsymphony")
if (length(find.package(package="slam",quiet=TRUE))==0) install.packages("slam")
if (length(find.package(package="lpSolve",quiet=TRUE))==0) install.packages("lpSolve")
if (length(find.package(package="Rglpk",quiet=TRUE))==0) install.packages("Rglpk")
if (length(find.package(package="slam",quiet=TRUE))==0) install.packages("slam")
require(Rsymphony)
require(slam)
require(lpSolve)
require(Rglpk)

#making sure SC is not a factor
t0["SC"] <- as.character(t0$SC)

#separating the SC and FP handling
t0_FP <- t0[t0$prop_to_handle=="FP",]
t0_SC <- t0[t0$prop_to_handle=="SC",]

#sparse constraint matrix for SC
SC.ID.mat <- xtabs(~SC+ID,t0_SC,sparse=T)

#sparse constraint matrix for FP
FP.ID.mat <- xtabs(~FP+ID,t0_FP,sparse=T)

NIDs_vs_FP <- table(t0_FP[["FP"]]) 

N.FP <- length(NIDs_vs_FP)
N.ID <- length(dimnames(SC.ID.mat)[[2]])
N.SC <- length(dimnames(SC.ID.mat)[[1]])

N.ID.SC <- as.vector(xtabs(N~SC,t0_SC[!duplicated(t0_SC$SC),]))

NIDs_vs_SC <- table(t0_SC[["SC"]])
N.ID.SC[(unname(NIDs_vs_SC - N.ID.SC) < 0)] <- NIDs_vs_SC[(unname(NIDs_vs_SC - N.ID.SC) < 0)]

#converting the sparse matrices from xtabs to the format accepted by Rglpk
FP.ID.mat <- as.simple_triplet_matrix(FP.ID.mat)
SC.ID.mat <- as.simple_triplet_matrix(SC.ID.mat)

#putting together the overall constraint matrix
cm <- rbind(cbind(FP.ID.mat,-simple_triplet_diag_matrix(NIDs_vs_FP)),cbind(FP.ID.mat,-simple_triplet_diag_matrix(NIDs_vs_FP)),cbind(SC.ID.mat,simple_triplet_zero_matrix(N.SC,N.FP)))

#making a non-sparse overall constraint matrix for lpSolve
cm2 <- as.matrix(cm)

#directions and rhs of the constraints
cdir <- c(rep("<=",N.FP),rep(">=",N.FP),rep("==",N.SC))
crhs <- unname(c(rep(0,N.FP),1-NIDs_vs_FP,N.ID.SC))

#objective vector, assigning -1 to each FP feature
cobj <- c(rep(0,N.ID),rep(-1,N.FP))

#solution using Rsymphony
sol.Rsymphony <- Rsymphony_solve_LP (cobj, cm, cdir, crhs, types = "B", max = FALSE, verbosity=0, first_feasible = FALSE)$solution

#solution using lpSolve
sol.lpSolve <- lp("min", cobj, cm2, cdir, crhs, all.bin=TRUE, num.bin.solns = 2,  use.rw = FALSE, transpose.constraints = TRUE)$solution

#solution using Rglpk
sol.Rglpk <- Rglpk_solve_LP (cobj, cm, cdir, crhs, types = "B", max = FALSE, control=list(verbose=TRUE,presolve=FALSE))$solution

#comparison of the solutions
sol.Rsymphony
#[1] 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
sol.lpSolve
#[1] 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
sol.Rglpk
#[1] 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Both `Rsymphony` and `Rglpk` find a single solution, and it's a different one in each case; `lpSolve` finds both solutions.

Unfortunately I can't use `lpSolve` on my actual problem because it's too large, so not only the actual solving would take too long, but I couldn't even make the initial matrix. I could try playing with the 'dense.const' option...

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Some random remarks: 1. Every "sane" solver is exploiting sparsity. clp/cbc, glpk, lpsolve, symphony. Your question is then: which R-wrapper supports this. 2. Clp is an LP-solver (only). To be accurate, you will want to use Cbc (the MIP-variant based on Clp). 3. Presolve might generate a different solution (if not unique); but not a different objective. In your case it's a bug, or what i think: you might interpret the output wrongly (or the output is presented wrongly). 4. Don't focus on presolve-techniques: focus on some R-wrapper which is able to use sparse-matrices (until fed to solvers)

Comment: Thank you @sascha. 1: indeed, I would like to use R. lpSolve has a 'dense.const' option that should allow to input sparse matrices, but as a solver it's slower than the other ones I tried. For Rsymphony, I will try to submit a sparse constraint matrix and see what happens. 2. OK, good to know 3. Two Rglpk presolve=F tasks are still running as we speak; if and when they finish I will check if the solution has the same obj as the presolved one. 4. OK; not sure where to look though; if I could choose I would go for Rsymphony, as it reports all solutions, not only the first found like Rglpk does.

Comment: I can't give any R-related tips, but i'm sceptical about `I would go for Rsymphony, as it reports all solutions, not only the first found like Rglpk does`. This is very unnatural in MIP-solving and basically reduces to add nogood and warm-start. Of course there is also the danger of having exponentially many solutions. (in commercial solvers there is stuff like SolutionPools; but well... those and their "guarantees" are another story). (in terms of the presolve-thing: instead of waiting hours to obtain a comparable solution: make your problem smaller for this task)

Comment: In fact Rsymphony has an option to decide whether to report all equivalent solutions or only the first one found. But I see your point. Further searches revealed that sparse matrices are indeed handled by Rsymphony. In [this webpage](https://rdrr.io/cran/Rsymphony/src/R/sparse.R) some commands are defined to turn standard matrices into the format Rsymphony uses. And [this post](http://strimas.com/prioritization/ilp-field-guide/) compares several solvers and shows that a slam sparse matrix is submitted to the Rsymphony solver. Thank you again for your advice!

Comment: I'll edit my post adding an example of application of Rsymphony and lpSolve in R, to illustrate the kind of problem I'm trying to solve, in case someone can suggest improvements in the code.

Comment: BTW, I just tried Rsymphony on my real-life large problem, and it's MUCH faster than Rglpk... I think I will stick with Rsymphony now that I know how to feed it sparse matrices.